# scope of variable in the angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I know it's silly question but would like to know exact scope of variable of this.

I have tried following and if i make any changes in data, response is getting changed too.

I have tried following:

```js
private response;
private data;

getdata() {
  this.service.getdata().subscribe((res: any) => {

    if (res) {
      this.response = res;
      this.data = res;
    }
  });
}
```

If i use data as input parameter for other component and make any changes on that, my this.response is also getting changed.

I am not sure what to do to retain the previous data.

Answer (score 1):

Its because both response and data are sharing the same object reference.

Your code within if condition is nothing but a shallow copy of each other

```
this.response = this.data = res;
```

Hence when you change one value the other value also gets changed,

In order to avoid this from happening you can do the following

```
this.data = Object.assign({},res);
```

OR

```
this.data = {...res}
```

Read [this](https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c) for more details on shallow copy and deep copy

Comment: so how to avoid that? How I can get the unchanged data?